# conditioning when an else block get executed for second time

Tags: perl

Hi, I am generating numbers inside the tags based on the style's

E.g

```
 <list-bull>
 <P_list-bull>Use Microsoft Windows accessibility  </P_list-bull>
 <P_list-bull>   Magnify the display </P_list-bull>
 <P_list-simple>   Change the size of text and icons </P_list-simple>
 <P_list-simple>   Convert the text displayed  </P_list-simple>
 <P_list-num>   Change the contrast </P_list-num>
 <P_list-simple>text and icons </P_list-simple>
 <P_list-bull>Microsoft accessibility </P_list-bull>
 </list-bull>
```

In above example is my input. I want to generate numbers based on the style's(bull,simple,num), In the first occurrence(any type) i ve to generate one(1) inside the tag, Then 2 for the second style and so on....

I want output in below format

```
 <list-bull>
 <P_list-bull(1)>Use Microsoft Windows accessibility  </P_list-bull(1)>
 <P_list-bull(1)>   Magnify the display </P_list-bull(1)>
 <P_list-simple(2)>   Change the size of text and icons </P_list-simple(2)>
 <P_list-simple(2)>   Convert the text displayed  </P_list-simple(2)>
 <P_list-num(3)>   Change the contrast </P_list-num(3)>
 <P_list-simple(2)>text and icons </P_list-simple(2)>
 <P_list-bull(1)>Microsoft accessibility </P_list-bull(1)>
 </list-bull>
```

i try this below code but i d't know where to fix the condition

```
 while($str =~ /<list-(bull|num|alpha|roman|simple)(?:(?:(?!<\/list-\1>).)*)<\/list-\1>/sgi){
$str =~ s#<list-(bull|num|alpha|roman|simple)(?:(?:(?!<\/list-\1>).)*)<\/list-\1>#&List_find($&,$1)#sgei;
  }
 sub List_find
 {
 my ($line,$type) = @_;
 my $currentlevel = 0;
 my $line1;
 while($line =~ s/<P_list-(bull|num|alpha|roman|simple)(?:(?:(?!<\/P_list-\1>).)*)    <\/P_list-\1>/&Listnum($&)/sgie){}



sub Listnum
{
my $line2 = @_[0];

my ($style,$cont);
if($line2 =~ /<P_list-(.*?)>(.*?)<\/P_list-\1>/sgi)
{
$style = $1;
$cont = $2;
my $id =1;
if($type eq $style){
$line2 = "<P_list-$style($id)>$cont</P_list-$style($id)>";

}
else{

    $line2 =~ /<P_list-(.*?)>(.*?)<\/P_list-\1>/s;
    my $temp = $1;

    if($style eq $temp)
        {

    $id++;
    $line2 = "<P_list-$style($id)>$cont</P_list-$style($id)>";
        }
    else
        {
    $id = $id+2;        

    $line2 = "<P_list-$style($id)>$cont</P_list-$style($id)>";          
        }
    }
    return "$line2";
}
}
```

I compare the first list item tag with the first list type(bull) if its is correct it will generate one otherwise two, In else part i want to check second and third type

plz give some suggestions

Comment: Why don't you use a proper XML parser?

Comment: ... and let it generate valid XML...

Comment: Is there is any possibilities to generate number without XML parser?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use one? [Yes, even you can use CPAN.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=693828)

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You're creating invalid XML and that seems like bad design.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why not to use some xml parser, but anyway..

get all styles as a hash keys, something like that:

```
my %styles=();
my $i=1;
while($text=~/P_list-([a-zA-Z]+)/gsm) {
    $styles{$1}=$i++ if !$styles{$1};
}
```

then just substitute them all

```
foreach my $k (keys %styles) {
    my $what_you_have="P_list-$k";
    my $what_you_want="P_list-$k($styles{$k})";
    $text=~s/$what_you_have/$what_you_want/gsm;
}
```

assuming that `$text` contains your whole input